# react: how to pass in URLs for REST APIs

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

Starting to learn react and couldn't find the answer to this on the internet. Maybe I don't know what terms to use.

My backend is django and I want to be able to pass in URLs for REST APIs to my React front end.
I don't want to hard code them in react as they are already defined in django.
It makes sense to me that I would want to render a script tag on my html template that contains an object containing the URL values.

e.g. the django template would have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var CONFIG = {
    some_url : '{% url "my-api" %}'
  }
</script>
```

(for those not familiar with django, that {% url %} tag renders a url like /path/to/myapi)

Then in my React Stores/Actions I would just refer to CONFIG.some_url.

Is this the right way to do it? Or is there a better way to make this information available to my react components.

------------ Edit -----------------

Using webpack to transpile the jsx files and using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) to integrate everything. this means that the django templates are completely rendered before the jsx is loaded on top.
As a result the template tags cannnot run inside the jsx files.

Answer (score 3):

Even though you're using django-webpack-loader(I am too), you still can pass props to your React app. You can proceed like this:

1) Resolve the absolute backend url in your view.py:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context['APIROOT_URL'] = reverse('api-root', request=self.request)
    return context
```

2) Pass the context prop to the html template

```
    <div id="react-app"></div>

<script>
    window.__APIROOT_URL__= '{{ APIROOT_URL }}';
    window.react_mount = document.getElementById('react-app');
</script>
{% render_bundle 'main' %}
```

3) Finally inside your app, get the property like this:

```
const apirootUrl = window.__APIROOT_URL__
```

Comment: this is pretty much what i'm doing, albeit in a slightly more structured way. thanks

Comment: You can also use `localStorage` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 0):

pass it as props:

```
<MyComponent src={% url %} />
```

Comment: forgot to mention i'm using webpack and the django templates are  fully rendered before the jsx is ever even loaded. I'll add additional detail to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Put following plugin in your webpack configuration:-

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.environ),
    }
  })
  ],
```

Run the webpack command as follows:-

```
environ=local webpack
```

or

```
 environ=production webpack -p //for production
```

Create a constants file where you keep  a function which returns API
   urls based on environment variable set above.(local,dev,production).

```
const api_url=function(){
  let api_url=//production api url
  if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'local'){
    //local api url
  }
  else if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'){
    //dev api url
  }
  return api_url;
}

export const url= api_url();
```

Import this in your componentDidMount() call the api using ajax/fetch/axios

```
import {url} from ../constants 

componentDidMount(){
   //api call
}
```

If you are using django and react together I would strongly suggest to look at [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader) once

Comment: thanks. I'm not completely clear on this approach. Is the constants file actually a django template? I'm not clear on how the jsx files will know how to load the constants file if it is on the django side. Are you recommending I hardcode the paths in a js file on the webpack side?

Comment: yes not hardcode but based on environment change the urls. You would create a constant.jsx file and import that in your components, then compile your project using webpack. Your jsx components would first be compiled into a single js bundle file. Place that file in your html. Is it clear now?

Comment: what happens when i change a path in django? Do I need to manually update this constant.jsx file?

Comment: I m assuming your apis would be built up first right? Thats the way it should work. If there is any change in django just update base_url in constants.jsx.

Comment: Also I would suggest you should segregate the front end and back end. As in build up front end completely on react and backend on django-rest. Involving templates with reactjs can get really messy. Trust me been there seen that :)

Comment: I c. i'm precisely looking for a solution where the single source of truth for the url endpoints is defined in django and not manually maintained in seperate js files. I'm not looking to involve templates with react, just avoid manually maintaining the API urls. This problem wouldn't be unique to django i think, it would be shared by any react implementation that would be consuming REST API endpoints where we didn't want to hard code the URLs. i.e. we expect the URLs to be provided to the front end via some mechanism from the back end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122443/discussion-between-harkirat-saluja-and-w).